# remove brackets that has a letter but not when it has a symbol inside

Tags: python-3.x

```
input_a = 'Hell(o) how a(re) you ? (.)'
output_a = 'Hello how are you ? (.)'
```

Remove the brackets where there is an alphabet in it but does not remove the 
brackets that has a symbol in it.
I have tried re.sub but it removes all the brackets. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
input_a = 'Hell(o) how a(re) you ? (.)'
output_a = []
i = 0
while i<len(input_a):
    if input_a[i] !="(":
        output_a.append(input_a[i])
        i=i+1
        continue
    else:
        if input_a[i+1].isalpha():
            i=i+1
            while input_a[i]!=")":
                output_a.append(input_a[i])
                i =i+1
            i = i+1
        else:
            while input_a[i]!=")":
                output_a.append(input_a[i])
                i=i+1
output_a = "".join(output_a)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if input_a was not a string but a list of strings. For instance: input_a= ['Hell(o) how a(re) you ? (.)' , 'I a(m) fi(ne) thank you .(.)']

Comment: in that case, you define that code as a function.
I write it another answer. it is hard to write in the comment

Answer (score 0):

In that case(you said on comment), it can be solved like below.

```
input_as= ['Hell(o) how a(re) you ? (.)' , 'I a(m) fi(ne) thank you .(.)']
output_as =[]
for input_a in input_as:
    output_a = []
    i = 0
    while i<len(input_a):
        if input_a[i] !="(":
            output_a.append(input_a[i])
            i=i+1
            continue
        else:
            if input_a[i+1].isalpha():
                i=i+1
                while input_a[i]!=")":
                    output_a.append(input_a[i])
                    i =i+1
                i = i+1
            else:
                while input_a[i]!=")":
                    output_a.append(input_a[i])
                    i=i+1
    output_a = "".join(output_a)
    output_as.append(output_a)
print(output_as)
```